# Android HTTPClient Support PATCH method

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Using 5.2.0GA SDK, also tried with 5.1.2GA, the HTTPClient does not support the PATCH method.  Found a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19564) that says resolved at 5.1.2 but still throws the error:

```
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-19) [13162,99993] HTTP Error (java.net.ProtocolException): Unknown method 'PATCH'; must be one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE]
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: java.net.ProtocolException: Unknown method 'PATCH'; must be one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE]
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:685)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.setRequestMethod(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:144)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1137)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Any thoughts or work arounds?

Comment: Can you close this, since the response on the Jira ticket was that this is an Android limitation not a Titanium issue? Of course, they never should have marked that ticket as "resolved/fixed" but that is how Appcelerator tends to do it.

Comment: Thanks @skypanther, I've reopened and resolved it as *Not Our Bug* now.